# Azure VM: The user account did not work issues while trying to connect from Mac

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a Microsoft Azure Virtual Machine with OS Windows (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter). I am trying to connect from Macbook via Microsoft Remote Desktop but I got an error like this

[image: error image]

I have searched about this issue on web but I couldn't solve this problem. I have tried some different formats like

```
<VMName>\Username
Password

\Username
Password
```

but these don't work for me.

I am using;

- MacOS: BigSur 11.4
- VM OS: Windows (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter)
- Microsoft Remote Desktop Version: 10.6.6

Comment: did you try with .\username? Also are you able to login from a different machine (another mac or windows, or using something like bastion? You should also hide the ip address of your machine - I tried to login to that IP, I can see that anyone is allowed to connect to it - meaning there are no nsg rules to whitelist your mac IP only.

Comment: @KedMardemootoo I have tried .\username after your advice but It also does not work, unfortunately. Additionally, I tried from a windows machine but I could not log in again. Finally thank you very much to warn me about IP. I will hide.

Comment: Ok are you able to remote to that machine at all from outside? How do you login at the moment (i.e what works)? Did you check if windows is configured to allow RDP? https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-enable-remote-desktop-in-windows-server-2019/

Comment: This is a new virtual machine I have not logged in to yet. I can't make the settings from the link. @KedMardemootoo

Comment: Ah ok so your issue should be more generic - it's not about not being able to login from a Mac but rather not being able to access the machine at all. Here are a few things you can try: enable/check boot diagnostics to find out where the VM is stuck at. If it shows a login screen then proceed to try using the serial console to login to the machine using cmd using the same username and passwords. If these do not work, consider resetting the password from the reset password page, still under your VM page.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the password in the password reset page. It worked for me.